# vb.net - Searching file based on pattern

Tags: vb.net

Struggling to write the code which will find file based on pattern

Name of File: DailyLoad_YYYYMMDDHHMMgifkm.csv (DailyLoad , then time stamp, then set of five characters and then extension)

So daily I need to match if we receive the above file in our source directory. Struggling to write code to do comparison

```
File Name in Database: DailyLoad_YYYYMMDDHHMMgifkm.csv
File Name received in Source Directory: DailyLoad_201307231010gifkm.csv
```

We need to check that time stamp in file name is of of today as files for other day might exist in the same folder

Can anyone please help?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Docs\ParentDirectory")
Dim ioFileInfo = dir.GetFiles("DailyLoad_" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "*gifkm.csv")
```